# Convert python3 JSON to command line string

Tags: python, json, string, dictionary

I have a JSON file that looks like this:

```
{
    "options": {
        "--singleseed": "Eugene Ionesco",
        "--booktitle": "Rhinoceros"
    }
}
```

I am loading it via

```
with open('/tmp/pagekicker/test.json') as json_data:
     d = json.load(json_data)
     s = str(d)
```

I now want to convert this to the following string:

```
--singleseed "Eugene Ionesco" --booktitle "Rhinoceros"
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over the dictionary. Build a string

```
data = {
    "options": {
        "--singleseed": "Eugene Ionesco",
        "--booktitle": "Rhinoceros"
    }
}

s = ' '.join( '{} "{}"'.format(k, v) for k,v in data['options'].items() )

print(s)  # --singleseed "Eugene Ionesco" --booktitle "Rhinoceros"
```

Comment: This does not seem to produce the quotes around the values, e.g., "Eugene Ionesco", which are important.
'
with open('/tmp/pagekicker/test.json') as json_data:
                d = json.load(json_data)
                s = ""
                for k,v in d['options'].items():
                    s += (2*"{} ").format(k, v)
                    print(s)
                cli = commandpath + ' ' + s
                print('cli will be ' + cli)
                args = shlex.split(cli)
                print(args)

'
produces 

--booktitle Rhinoceros --singleseed Eugene Ionesco